# Using Jmeter JDBC Parameter values as HTTP request input

Tags: apache, http, jdbc, request, jmeter

I need to use the parameter values that I set in a JDBC request as the input to my XML's in my http request. For example my jdbc request is running the query for two vendor numbers. I need to later use those vendor numbers to disable them through an http request.

Answer (score 0):

You have "Variable Names" section in the [JDBC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request%5C) sampler where you can specify where and how to store query results into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

For example I have a query which returns 2 arbitrary IDs form [MySQL/MariaDB `help_topic`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysqlhelp_topic-table/) table

```
mysql> select help_topic_id from help_topic limit 2;
+---------------+
| help_topic_id |
+---------------+
|           504 |
|           636 |
+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If I execute the same query in JMeter and put `id` into "Variable Names" field:

[image: JMeter JDBC Variables]

It will result into 3 JMeter Variables:

```
id_#=2
id_1=504
id_2=636
```

You can view what JMeter Variables are available along with their values using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination

[image: JMeter Variables from JDBC]

You will be able to refer the variables as `${id_1}` and `${id_2}` where required.

See [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) article for more details if needed

Comment: Ok now I have them providing results and I can use those results in the same thread group. Is it possible to use them in a separate thread group as well?